# Collapsible Paragraph with text using Pure css

Tags: html, css

I have used pure css to make a paragraph collapsible

A quick demo here:https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/qmo8hjz7/

```css
#module {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


#module #collapseExample.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#module #collapseExample.collapsing {
  height: 3rem;
}

#module a.collapsed::after {
  content: '+ Show More';
}

#module a:not(.collapsed)::after {
  content: '- Show Less';
}
```

```html
<div id="module" class="container">
  <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
  <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
    Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder
    beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin shankle.
    Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
  </p>
  <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
</div>
<div id="module" class="container">
  <h3>Bacon Ipsum</h3>
  <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
    Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner picanha tri-tip biltong leberkas salami meatball tongue filet mignon landjaeger tail. Kielbasa salami tenderloin picanha spare ribs, beef ribs strip steak jerky cow. Pork chop chicken ham hock beef ribs turkey jerky. Shoulder
    beef capicola doner, tongue tail sausage short ribs andouille. Rump frankfurter landjaeger t-bone, kielbasa doner ham hock shankle venison. Cupim capicola kielbasa t-bone, ball tip chicken andouille venison pork chop doner bacon beef ribs kevin shankle.
    Short loin leberkas tenderloin ground round shank, brisket strip steak ham hock ham.
  </p>
  <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
</div>
```

The problem am facing is i have multiple paragraph like this like i have shown in the ***jsfiddle*** but i dont want to open every div mean only expand the div i have clicked on click of `showmore` and am only allowed to use pure `css` is there any way i could achieve it.Thanks in advance

***UPDATE:*** I have used a single `div` with the `id` to show the paragraph and this come inside a `datatable` and there are almost 100 different paragraph. I can use a `class` name instead of that will it be possible?

Comment: Just FYI, it's not even close to pure CSS, it is bootstrap's javascript module that makes it work.

Comment: @AntoineB Thanks for that !!! But do u have any experience of handling this situation i could use ```class``` instead of ```ID``` by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 collapsible panel without id or data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525122/bootstrap-3-collapsible-panel-without-id-or-data)

Answer (score 2):

Use different IDs. Anyway you can't use same ID more than once in the same page.

Comment: @AndyHolmes Yes it does, having the same ID twice is what causes the issue for the OP.

Comment: @AntoineB my bad, didn't realise it was BootStrap. Comment removed and upvoted.

Comment: @Chami M i agree and i know i cannot use same id on different ```div``` but my problem is is it possible to do it with ```css``` i may use class name instead of ```id```

Comment: @marceloo1223 You cannot use class as a trigger here. Only an ID you can use as a trigger. Please refer https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: @ChamiM so are you saying it is not possible with just ```css```?

Comment: @marceloo1223 Cannot do with pure css. But, In your fiddle, you have used bootrstrap. With bootstrap, you can make it work with IDs.

Answer (score 0):

We can now use CSS line-clamp property. CSS property that will contain text to a given amount of lines when used in combination with display: -webkit-box.

For cross-browser support check:
https://caniuse.com/?search=line-clamp

If you are using tailwindcss, tailwindlabs have an official plugin just for this:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-line-clamp

```css
.text-collapse {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}

.text-collapse:hover {
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-collapse">Kitty power munch on tasty moths but put butt in owner's face yet murf pratt ungow ungow yet whatever. Do doodoo in the litter-box, clickityclack on the piano, be frumpygrumpy pet me pet me pet me pet me, bite, scratch, why are you petting me for paw at your fat belly. Dead stare with ears cocked to pet a cat, rub its belly, endure blood and agony, quietly weep, keep rubbing belly. Unwrap toilet paper kitty poochy, so ha ha, you're funny i'll kill you last burrow under covers need to chase tail stand in front of the computer screen kitty scratches couch bad kitty. Bite nose of your human blow up sofa in 3 seconds lick plastic bags for lick plastic bags or hide when guests come over, for kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff. Poop in a handbag look delicious and drink the soapy mopping up water then puke giant foamy fur-balls put toy mouse in food bowl run out of litter box at full speed . Meow in empty rooms lick left leg for ninety minutes, still dirty pretend not to be evil.</p>
```